# Ansible Jinja2 for printout produces duplicate result

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

Ansible version 2.2, Mac OS X El Capitan

I'm trying to generate list of port mappings.

When i run code like that

```
---
- hosts: [localhost]
  sudo: True 
  pre_tasks:
    - debug: 
        var: "{% for id in range(100,102) %}  
                '{{ id }}'
            {% endfor %}"
```

I expect to get result like that:

> "'100'  '101'"

But instead I get result:

> " '100'  '101' ": "100101"

It's not very obvious why I get such result. It looks like it creates some kind of map from the results, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the expected result, you just see inconsistent output because you used `var` parameter instead of `msg` in the `debug` module.

Try:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "{% for id in range(100,102) %}  
                '{{ id }}'
              {% endfor %}"
```

---

In more complex cases, you might consider an even more reliable way of debugging, by saving the content to the file and checking the contents. This would eliminate the influence of callback plugins that display the Ansible log.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - copy: 
        dest: ./result.txt
        content: "{% for id in range(100,102) %}  
                    '{{ id }}'
                  {% endfor %}"
```

And then:

```
cat ./result.txt
```